Close popup by clicking the outside area using jQuery
I am working with this tutorial to create a popup using Divi. https://divilover.com/divi-popup-without-plugins-tutorial/ I am having difficulty modifying the javascript to close the popup by clicking the outside area. Here is the code: ( I have tried many edits but StackOverflow is complaining I have already entered too much code. )


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    
    $('.dl-popup-content').each(function(){
        $(this).wrap('<div class="dl-popup-wrapper"><div class="dl-popup-inside">');
    });
        
        
    $('.dl-popup-trigger, .dl-menu-popup > a').off().click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        SectionID = $(this).attr('href');
        $(SectionID).closest('.dl-popup-wrapper').addClass('popup-is-visible');
        $(SectionID).closest('.et_builder_inner_content').addClass('popup-is-visible');
        $('body').addClass('dl-noscroll');
                
    }); 
            
    $('.dl-popup-close').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.popup-is-visible').removeClass('popup-is-visible');
        $('body').removeClass('dl-noscroll');
        
        var PopupVideoIframe = $(this).closest('.dl-popup-content').find('.et_pb_video_box iframe');
        var PopupVideoSrc = PopupVideoIframe.attr("src");
        PopupVideoIframe.attr("src", PopupVideoSrc);
        
        var PopupVideoHTML = $(this).closest('.dl-popup-content').find('.et_pb_video_box video');
        PopupVideoHTML.trigger('pause');
    });


}); 
/* Show/hide the popup overlay wrapper when "is-visible" class changes, apply the CSS to frontend only */
body:not(.et-fb) .dl-popup-wrapper {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:990;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.14,.06,.41,1.39);
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
body:not(.et-fb) .dl-popup-wrapper.popup-is-visible {
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}


/* Allow the content inside the popup wrapper to scroll */
.dl-popup-inside {
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* Prevent Body from Scrolling when Popup is visible */
body.dl-noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Center Align Popup Content inside the Section */
.dl-popup-content {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.dl-popup-content .et_pb_row {
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
}


/* Adjust the position of the popup overlay for admin bar */
@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:782px) {
  body:not(.et-fb).admin-bar .dl-popup-wrapper {
    top:46px;
  }
}
@media (min-width:783px) {
  body:not(.et-fb).admin-bar .dl-popup-wrapper {
    top:32px;
  }
}

/* Mave the popup on top of other elements */
.et_builder_inner_content.popup-is-visible {
  z-index:99999;
}

/* Add a hand cursor to the close trigger element */
.dl-popup-close {
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* Add Row animation when popup is triggered */
.dl-popup-wrapper.popup-is-visible .et_pb_row:not(.dl-popup-close) {animation:scale-in .5s cubic-bezier(.14,.06,.41,1.39) both; animation-delay: .5s; }
@keyframes scale-in{0%{transform:scale(0.3);opacity:0}100%{transform:scale(1);opacity:1}}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#contact" class="dl-popup-trigger">Click here</a>
<div id="contact" class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 dl-popup-content et_section_regular">
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_0  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_icon et_pb_icon_0 dl-popup-close"> <span class="et_pb_icon_wrap "><span class="et-pb-icon"></span></span> </div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_0  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
        <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
          <h4 class="center red">Popup Content</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I have tried several forms of the following with no result:
$(document).click(function(e){
if($(e.target).closest('#contact').length != 0) return false;
$('#contact').hide();
}); THANK YOU!

To make the popup close when clicking outside of it, you need to add event listeners that detect clicks outside the .dl-popup-content area. Here's an update to your JavaScript that will properly handle this functionality.


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    // Wrap the popup content inside a wrapper
    $('.dl-popup-content').each(function() {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="dl-popup-wrapper"><div class="dl-popup-inside">');
    });

    // Trigger to open the popup when the button/link is clicked
    $('.dl-popup-trigger, .dl-menu-popup > a').off().click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var SectionID = $(this).attr('href');
        $(SectionID).closest('.dl-popup-wrapper').addClass('popup-is-visible');
        $(SectionID).closest('.et_builder_inner_content').addClass('popup-is-visible');
        $('body').addClass('dl-noscroll');
    });

    // Close the popup when the close button is clicked
    $('.dl-popup-close').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        closePopup();
    });

    // Close the popup when clicking outside the popup content (wrapper)
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        // If the click is outside of the popup content, close the popup
        if (!$(e.target).closest('.dl-popup-content').length && !$(e.target).closest('.dl-popup-trigger').length) {
            closePopup();
        }
    });

    // Function to close the popup
    function closePopup() {
        $('.popup-is-visible').removeClass('popup-is-visible');
        $('body').removeClass('dl-noscroll');
        
        // If there's a video inside the popup, stop the video
        var PopupVideoIframe = $('.popup-is-visible').find('.et_pb_video_box iframe');
        var PopupVideoSrc = PopupVideoIframe.attr("src");
        PopupVideoIframe.attr("src", PopupVideoSrc); // Reset the iframe src to stop the video

        var PopupVideoHTML = $('.popup-is-visible').find('.et_pb_video_box video');
        PopupVideoHTML.trigger('pause'); // Pause the video
    }
});
/* General Popup Wrapper */
body:not(.et-fb) .dl-popup-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 990;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.14, .06, .41, 1.39);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent overlay */
}

/* Make the popup visible */
body:not(.et-fb) .dl-popup-wrapper.popup-is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* Allow content inside the popup wrapper to scroll */
.dl-popup-inside {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Prevent body from scrolling when the popup is visible */
body.dl-noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Center Align Popup Content */
.dl-popup-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: white; /* Popup background color */
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Row inside popup (adjusting margins) */
.dl-popup-content .et_pb_row {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Close button inside the popup */
.dl-popup-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

/* Adjust the position of the popup overlay for the admin bar (if any) */
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 782px) {
  body:not(.et-fb).admin-bar .dl-popup-wrapper {
    top: 46px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 783px) {
  body:not(.et-fb).admin-bar .dl-popup-wrapper {
    top: 32px;
  }
}

/* Scale animation for the popup when it appears */
.dl-popup-wrapper.popup-is-visible .et_pb_row:not(.dl-popup-close) {
  animation: scale-in 0.5s cubic-bezier(.14, .06, .41, 1.39) both;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes scale-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Hand cursor for close trigger element */
.dl-popup-close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Prevent scrolling of the body when the popup is visible */
body.dl-noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Click outside detection for closing the popup */
.dl-popup-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Overlay background */
}

/* Make popup content scrollable */
.dl-popup-inside {
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Make popup content responsive */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dl-popup-content {
    max-width: 95%;
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#contact" class="dl-popup-trigger">Click here</a>

<div id="contact" class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 dl-popup-content et_section_regular">
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_0 et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_icon et_pb_icon_0 dl-popup-close">
        <span class="et_pb_icon_wrap"><span class="et-pb-icon"></span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_0 et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
        <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
          <h4 class="center red">Popup Content</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you very much for this. While it works flawlessly above, unfortunately, there is no effect on my page. All else works, just not clicking the outside. Do you have any ideas of what would cause this? Very much appreciated.

Realized you also adjusted CSS. Thank you very much!
